# Update request headers before goind to controller

Tags: java, spring-boot

I can't update a header inside my interceptor before it gets to my controller, through the interceptor I would like to modify an already present header

```
public class MyInterceptor implements Filter {
   

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        //something
        //myHeaders is still present when send a request
        req.setAttribute("myHeaders","someValue");
        chain.doFilter(req, rest);
    }
}
```

So that inside the controller I can get the modified header:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class FooClass{
    
        @Autowired
        private Service service;

        @GetMapping("/foo")
        public ResponseEntity<Void> fooApi(
                @RequestHeader(value = "myHeaders") String myHeaders,
        ) {
            service.doSomething(myHeaders);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
        }
}
```

How could I do? I tried to do some research but failed.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Filter` you can create an anonymous subclass of `HttpServletRequestWrapper`, override the method `public String getHeader(String name)` so that it returns a specific value for the header name you care about (and delegates to `super.getHeader(String)` if it's not the header name you care about).

Something like this:

```java
  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
   HttpServletRequest servletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

   HttpServletRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(servletRequest) {
      @Override
      public String getHeader(String name) {
        if ("myHeader".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
          return "Some value";
        }

        return super.getHeader(name);
      }
    };

    chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response);
  }
```

Comment: This not works, when retrieve the value in controller the value not changed